# How to display NSMutableAttributedString in Text view in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, attributedstring

Given a string, `The * quick * brown * fox * jumps * over * the * lazy * dog`, I'm applying font modifiers as follows in order to style **all occurrences of asterisk** differently than the rest of the text.

```
func customDesc(_ text: String) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
        let asteriskTextRange = (text as NSString).range(of: "*")
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .semibold)])
        attributedString.setAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .heavy)], range: asteriskTextRange)
        return attributedString
    }
```

It seems `range(of:)` will only pick the first occurrence so how do update all occurrences and display the resultant text in a `Text` view? I could not find any initialisers that accept `NSMutableAttributedString`. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: SwiftUI handles `AttributedString` natively not `NSAttributed(Mutable)String`, but `AttributedString` can be initialized with a `NSAttributedString`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/attributedstring/3856542-init So use that one

Comment: Side note, I'm not sure if that's intended or if you didn't saw the result yet, but you are modifying only the first asterisk, not all of them, as `range(of:)` returns only the first occurence found.

Comment: Ah! I'd like to change all occurrences as mentioned in my question. Did not realise `range(of:)` didn't do that. I've updated my question. @Larme based on your first comment, is there a way to get an `NSAttributedString ` from a `NSMutableAttributedString `?

Comment: `NSMutableAttributedString` inherits from `NSAttributedString` so the initializer should work in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Text`s take the Swift `AttributedString`s instead of the `NSAttributedString`s from Objective-C. You can convert to `AttributedString` simply by using one of its initialisers.

```
Text(AttributedString(customDesc(...)))
```

However, I would suggest that `customDesc` return a `AttributedString` directly, as it is more Swifty. You can use [`ranges(of:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection/ranges(of:)) to find all the ranges of a particular substring.

```
func customDesc(_ text: String) -> AttributedString {
    var attributedString = AttributedString(text)
    attributedString.font = Font.system(size: 15, weight: .semibold)

    for range in text.ranges(of: "*") {
        // this converts Range<String.Index> to Range<AttributedString.Index>
        if let lowerBound = AttributedString.Index(range.lowerBound, within: attributedString),
           let upperBound = AttributedString.Index(range.upperBound, within: attributedString) {
            let attrRange = lowerBound..<upperBound
            attributedString[attrRange].font = Font.system(size: 20, weight: .heavy)
        }
    }
    return attributedString
}
```

```
Text(customDesc(...))
```

Comment: I'll just add that since other people might be inspired by this answer and do something more like changing the asterisk character by other string, that if that's the case, use `text.ranges(of: "*").reversed()` or all the ranges might be altered and false once the second iteration in the loop starts.

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks! This works but I noticed that if I replace the * with say the dot symbol `‧` , then increasing the font size also causes it to become elevated from the text mid-line. Any idea why? I get that the asterisk(*) when typed is elevated when displayed but the dot displays fine if rendered with the same font size say 15 as the rest of the text compared to a higher font size say 18.

Comment: @batman That's... just how *font* works? Perhaps you want the baseline of the asterisks lower? `attributedString[attrRange].baselineOffset = -5` or some other number.

Comment: Perfect! thanks :)